# Launch remote commands via SSH over a VPN

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, vpn

I have a Debian server (A) and two Raspberry Pi (B and C).

I want to launch commands on B and C from the server A. B is in the same subnet as A, but C is on a different subnet, connected to the first over an Ipsec VPN.

When I launch the following command on A, it's working on B but not on C :

```
ssh pi@B 'touch test'
```

is working.

```
ssh pi@C 'touch test'
```

is not working, hang immediately after launch, I have to Ctrl+C to exit.

And yet when I try to connect via SSH from A to C, with ssh pi@C everything's working fine.

Does someone have an idea ? What tests can I run to find what's causing this ?

I have in fact way more than 2 raspberry, I'm facing the same problem with all the Pi that are not on the same subnet than my server.

Edit : Like Jaroslav Kucera suggested, I tried an inscreased verbose on the ssh command, on B and on C to compare outputs.

It's blocking after that message on C :

```
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

Comment: Try to increase verbosity (-vvv parameter). Maybe it'll tell you something.

Comment: Just to confirm - can you ping C?

Comment: I can ping C from A. I will try an increased verbose tomorrow, i didn't thought about that, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work simply by adding -o IPQoS=cs0 to the ssh command :

```
ssh -o IPQoS=cs0 pi@C 'touch test'
```